# ORA-01000: máximo de cursores abertos excedido golang

Tags: oracle, golang

Eu tenho um serviço que executa uma pilha. Para isso, ele executa a leitura dessa pilha através de uma consulta no Oracle. Acontece que, após horas de execução, recebo a mensagem:

ORA-01000: máximo de cursores abertos excedido

Eu me pergunto o que pode estar acontecendo. Eu tenho uma variável global que abre a conexão e quando vou executar uma consulta sempre verifico sua conexão e a copio para a variável local.

Em Rows.Next (), pelo que li, quando ele verifica se não há mais linhas, ele fecha o cursor, então eu não poderia ter acumulado tantos cursores em aberto para exceder o limite.

Conexão ao banco:

```
type GERENCIACON struct {
DataBase *sql.DB
}

func (gc *GERENCIACON) F_FECHAR_CONEXAO() {
gc.DataBase.Close()
}

func (gc *GERENCIACON) F_ABRIR_CONEXAO()  { 
if gc.DataBase == nil || gc.DataBase.Ping() != nil {    
    gc.DataBase, _ = sql.Open("goracle", "X/X@10.0.254.10:1521/orcl")
}
}

var VGGerenciaConexao GERENCIACON
```

Estrutura para consulta:

```
type GERENCIACONSULTA struct {
DataBase *sql.DB
Rows *sql.Rows
}

func (gc *GERENCIACONSULTA) F_EXECUTA_CONSULTA(pSql string) {
VGGerenciaConexao.F_ABRIR_CONEXAO()
gc.DataBase = VGGerenciaConexao.DataBase
gc.Rows, _ = gc.DataBase.Query(pSql)
}
```

Serviço de Execução da pilha

```
 var vGerenciaConsulta CertanoLabsPackage.GERENCIACONSULTA
 var vSQL string

  for {
    vSQL = "select * from stack "   

   vGerenciaConsulta.F_EXECUTA_CONSULTA(vSQL)

      for vGerenciaConsulta.Rows.Next() {
      ...
     }

time.Sleep(time.Minute)
 }
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Cara, deixa eu te perguntar.. Quantos registros isso tá processando?

Comment: Você pode postar esse `Serviço de Execução` completo? Me parece que você está criando uma nova instancia de `GERENCIACONSULTA` cada vez que você executa esse código, que por sua vez abre uma nova conexão cada vez que você invoca `F_EXECUTA_CONSULTA`

Comment: O problema dos cursores em aberto não era a consulta, descobri que não estava fechando as operações DML. Verifiquei no banco e tinha mais de 5000 cursores aberto. Mas deu certo pessoal. Obrigado pela ajuda.